# Replacement for Archmage Antonidas in Mech Mage

Tags: hearthstone

As a [nice visualization of the Mech Mage decklists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cd2u.jpg) shows, all of the examined professional players use Archmage Antonidas in their Mech Mage decks. From what I understand Antonidas provides a lot more reach to the deck, you get enough spare parts to activate in in a Mech Mage and decks with such a low curve tend to run out of steam quickly if you don't win fast.

I wanted to try out one of these Mech Mage decks, but I don't have an Antonidas. The way it works is also unique, and I don't have any idea on which card could reasonably replace him. Which other cards, preferably non-legendary, could replace Antonidas in these decks and provide a similar function?

Comment: Just because there isnt a good replacement doesn't mean you cant make a mech mage deck, it works really well without it. Just replace it with something with similar bord influence and same cost ( another sky piloted golem for strifecro's deck for example )

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe that you'll find a non-legendary that would give you the same kind of reach and flexibility as an Archmage Antonidas. There simply is no other card in the game that gives you a fireball spell in hand.

The fireball that it gives you when you cast a spell is much more powerful than any other card you may get. If it lasts more than a round then the effect snowballs out of control. By that time in the game (turn 8-10) you could easily dish out 17 (2x Fireball + Archmage Antonidas attack) to 20 points of direct damage (2x Fireball + Archmage Antonidas attack + Frostbolt).

The only sort of viable alternatives that I've been able to find is a Ragnaros. It's a 8/8 on the board and deals 8 damage at the end of your turn, albeit randomly. If there is no answer for the Ragnaros, it's helping deal out significant damage per turn. Although he's vulnerable to Big Game Hunter.

Ysera might be another viable alternative because of all the cards it can possibly give you. It's a bit more of a defensive alternative where as Ragnaros is more aggressive.

Edit: After reviewing the cards, Jeeves may not be a bad idea either. Since you'll be lacking cards and most likely playing almost all your cards every turn in a mech mage style deck Jeeves can help you replenish your hand fairly quickly and you might be able to draw the extra few cards that you need.

Comment: Yes, i'm agree with BGH, but Ragn is too easy to counter in current meta. Also you cant use invis on it because it'll deal dmg and become visible

Comment: Do note, though, that OP asked that suggestions be non-legendary, preferably.

Comment: I address that right in my opening statement :)

Comment: Also keep in mind Antonidas only costs 7, so you can play him AND a secret to protect him in the same turn, also gaining a fireball in the process.

Comment: Gazlowe has the same sort of Spare Part synergy as Antonidas, though a bit slower since the minions he gives you are both random and will very likely not have Charge.

Answer (score 2):

At the stage of Archmage is used, usually you'll have some spare parts not enough minions/spells to play. There some options which you could choose.

- Flamestrike: not good enough since you won't be able to finish the game without extra dmg.
- Unstable Portal: no one wants to depend on this much luck in ranked games. But you'll probably have more fun by wining with this card.
- Sky-Piloted Golem: It looks like It'll do the job but by experience I can say a yeti or a harvest golem have more pressure than this card.
- Minions: there are a lot of choices here.

  - DrawCard: Ysera, Jeeves could do some job but the cards in the Minions section look more viable than these. Also DON'T PUT GADGETZAN in a mechmage deck. With the nerf its too slow and weak.
  - Pressure: Onyxia, Reaper, Ragnaros, Sneed, Gazlowe, Mogor Ogre, Lotheb are viable options along with the cards used in other decks than Reynads.

Between these cards my pick order would be:

1) Ragnaros: Mech is mage about board control and pressure. Ragnaros is one of the best cards to do this.
2) Sneed: Cause sneed rocks. Its like a bigger shedder. You'll have pressure for a lot of turns. Since Ragnaros is more agressive I'd pick rag first.
3) One of these by order if your deck doesn't already have. Mech-Yeti, Azure Drake, Harvest Golem.
4) Other cards could be used for experimental purpose like Gazlowe or Onyxia..

Answer (score 1):

Gadgetzan auctioneer would be a pretty obvious pick, seeing as it also plays well with all the spare parts.

Answer (score 0):

Anton is great lategame pick. So you had to find the same with strong snowballing effect.Most of them are legendaries. Ysera, which is OP with invisibility, Gazlowe with spare parts. But if you haven't it you can take Flamestrike/Echo.